# Xamarin Forms - Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.ImageRenderer.UpdateAspect()

Tags: xamarin.forms

I saw some post about it but, unlike them, me it only happens since the update of VS2015 to VS2017, any idea?

```
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.ImageRenderer.UpdateAspect()
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.ImageRenderer.<OnElementChanged>d__3.MoveNext()
    End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()"
```

My project is a Forms Portable Project, tell me if you want any details, I'll edit the question ! Also, I use a renderer for Android, but not for UWP, it works on android, but it shouldn't be the problem since it worked before

Thank in advance

Comment: It's weird, but I created another project, and copied back my work, piece by piece, and I found which `Image` was creating the problem. It's on a "splash page" which is here only to redirect to the Login page or the Main page, and I feel like, the pages are switching before the image could appears, maybe it's the problem, I don't know

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bug in Xamarin Forms: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37022

Updating Xamarin Forms should do the trick. I installed Xamarin.Forms version 2.3.5.239-pre3, which solved my problem.